# Azure Synapse Pipeline Stuck / Hung in-Progress state; how to debug? LocalVM runtime performance

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

This appears to be a common problem but a complete mystery for how to resolve.

This happens when I try to process many hundreds of files. My pipeline has 1588 items. It works great for an hour or so and then it gets down to a few items in progress and nothing happens. It just hangs like this.

- 1579 items succeeded
- 6 items failed
- 3 items cancelled (These were the ones stuck in progress.)

Most recent failure  of the 6 errors output:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "'Type=System.OutOfMemoryException,Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy EIP CSV Extract JB",
    "details": []
}
```

[image: 3 items stuck in progress]

If I process only 25 files in a trigger the pipeline runs fine. This hanging appears to happen only when I want it to run against hundreds of files at a time.

Since there is no clear error, I don't even understand how to debug this. It is very frustrating.

This is the output for each of those items:

```
For each: {
    "ItemsCount": "515"
}

IfSizeLargerThan25MB_FileExtension_txt_gz
{}

Copy EIP CSV Extract JBV2
{
"dataRead": 51933184,
"dataWritten": 0,
"filesRead": 1,
"filesWritten": 0,
"sourcePeakConnections": 1,
"sinkPeakConnections": 1,
"rowsRead": 10982475,
"rowsCopied": 10982475,
"copyDuration": 3562,
"throughput": 14.604,
"logFilePath": "copyactivity-logs/Copy EIP CSV Extract JB/....4ebb/",
"errors": [],
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "FC-xxxxxxx",
"usedParallelCopies": 1,
"executionDetails": [
    {
        "source": {
            "type": "FileServer"
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
            "region": "West US 3"
        },
        "status": "Canceled",
        "start": "9/20/2023, 5:10:19 PM",
        "duration": 3562,
        "usedParallelCopies": 1,
        "profile": {
            "queue": {
                "status": "Completed",
                "duration": 6
            },
            "transfer": {
                "status": "InProgress",
                "duration": 3556,
                "details": {
                    "listingSource": {
                        "type": "FileServer",
                        "workingDuration": 0
                    },
                    "readingFromSource": {
                        "type": "FileServer",
                        "workingDuration": 22
                    },
                    "writingToSink": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                        "workingDuration": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "detailedDurations": {
            "queuingDuration": 6,
            "transferDuration": 3556
        }
    }
],
"dataConsistencyVerification": {
    "VerificationResult": "Verified"
},
"durationInQueue": {
    "integrationRuntimeQueue": 6
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Thanks,

John

Comment: What is the batch count for ForEach loop?. I also faced the similar issue when I use a high number. I usually set it to 40 to 50.  Also, if you have big csv files then break them into small pieces and then process it

Comment: Nadeem, the batches are set to 10 on the ForEach. Each file is about 80-90MBs. Files are being copied from onprem to Azure cloud datalake, Parquet snappy.

Comment: I wondered, does setting the ForEach to sequential introduce more reliability into the pipeline?

Comment: We have a LocalVM runtime. Under nodes, Concurrent jobs are limited to 14.

Comment: What is the capacity of LocalVM? I am expecting if we increase the VM size, it should fix the issue

Comment: Nadeem, I am not sure. I have put a ticket in with my sys engineering team to investigate.

Comment: initial investigation shows high CPU usage on local VM during tests. This may be the source. When the VM gets more resources, I will retest and update this thread with the results.

Comment: We increased the memory on 6 cores from 16MB to 24MBs on the local VM. I then reran the pipeline on 2x as many files and it completed successfully with no errors, or stalls. Pretty sure the local VM resources were the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We increased the memory on 6 cores from 16MB to 24MBs on the local VM. I then reran the pipeline on 2x as many files and it completed successfully with no errors, or stalls. Pretty sure the local VM resources were the problem.

**Local VM Resources during hang, with out of memory pipeline errors:**
[image]

**Local VM Resources after increasing memory and running pipeline on 2x the files:**
[image]